# Accessing Elements/Attributes From XML Using DomXML

Tags: php, xml

I'm forced to use a server running PHP 4 and the XML service that's on the server is DomXML. My question is how do I access specific elements and attributes of the following XML document using DomXML? I tried the following with no results returned. Any help is appreciated...

```
if (!$xml = domxml_open_file($pathToXMLdoc)) {
//the above requires absolube path
exit("Could not access the XML source.");
}

$root = $xml->document_element();

echo($root->current_conditions->conditions['data'] . "<br>");

//XML FILE BELOW

<xml_api_reply version="1">

<weather module_id="0" tab_id="0" mobile_row="0" mobile_zipped="1" row="0" section="0">

<forecast_information>
   <city data="Carlsbad, CA"/>
   <postal_code data="92009"/>
   <latitude_e6 data=""/>
   <longitude_e6 data=""/>
   <forecast_date data="2012-03-29"/>
   <current_date_time data="2012-03-29 11:52:00 +0000"/>
   <unit_system data="US"/>
</forecast_information>

<current_conditions>
   <condition data="Partly Cloudy"/>
   <temp_f data="62"/>
   <temp_c data="17"/>
   <humidity data="Humidity: 65%"/>
   <icon data="/ig/images/weather/partly_cloudy.gif"/>
   <wind_condition data="Wind: SW at 4 mph"/>
</current_conditions>


</weather>

</xml_api_reply>
```

Comment: now is last day of 2012 March, and you still using PHP 4??? Good LUCK!

Comment: try using the xpath functions to query the dom tree.

Comment: I'm not using it by choice, it's what I have to work with. Thanks for nothing.